# Python. Конечные автоматы с многопоточностью. Почему так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Я написал такой код:

```
from enum import Enum
import time
import threading


class State(Enum):
    WAITING = 1
    WORKING = 2

def thread(my_func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        my_thread.start()
    return wrapper

@thread
def timeri():
    state = State.WORKING
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Закончил работать')
    print(state)
    state = State.WAITING

def main():
    state = State.WAITING
    while True:
        print(state)
        sms = input()

        if state == State.WAITING:
            print('Привет дружочек пирожочек')
            timeri()
        elif state == State.WORKING:
            print('Я занят')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Код, запускается, пишем сообщение, нас один раз приветствует, а после запускается таймер, которые работает 5 секунд и по идее, эти 5 секунд, он должен писать "я занят"
(Нужна именно много поточность, чтобы можно было писать и в момент его работы)

Но в результате он всегда пишет нам привет, почему так происходит?

```
`State.WAITING
Привет
Привет дружочек пирожочек
State.WAITING
а
Привет дружочек пирожочек
State.WAITING
Закончил работать
State.WORKING
а
Привет дружочек пирожочек
State.WAITING
```

Comment: внутри `timeri` свой `state`, внутри `main` - свой. Объявляйте его `global` и там и там, либо инкапсулируйте внутри объекта потока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заведите общую структуру данных и используйте ее:

```
...

@thread
def timeri():
    print('Начал работать')
    DATA['state'] = State.WORKING
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Закончил работать')
    print(DATA['state'])
    DATA['state'] = State.WAITING

DATA = {
    'state': State.WAITING
}

def main():
    DATA['state'] = State.WAITING
    while True:
        print(DATA['state'])
        sms = input()

        if DATA['state'] == State.WAITING:
            print('Привет дружочек пирожочек')
            timeri()
        elif DATA['state'] == State.WORKING:
            print('Я занят')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Или сделайте переменную `state` глобальной и в функции, где к ней присваивается значение укажите `global state`, тогда будет изменено значение глобальной переменной, а не создание локальной переменной:

```
...

@thread
def timeri():
    global state
    print('Начал работать')
    state = State.WORKING
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Закончил работать')
    print(state)
    state = State.WAITING

# Глобальная переменная
state = State.WAITING

def main():
    while True:
        print(state)
        sms = input()

        if state == State.WAITING:
            print('Привет дружочек пирожочек')
            timeri()
        elif state == State.WORKING:
            print('Я занят')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```